# How to filter on a date range for Sentinl?

Tags: elasticsearch

So we've started to implement Sentinl to send alerts. I have managed to get a count of errors sent if it exceeds a specified threshold.

What I'm really struggling with, is filtering for the last day!

Could someone please point me in the right direction!

Herewith the script:

```
{
  "actions": {
    "Email Action": {
      "throttle_period": "0h0m0s",
      "email": {
        "to": "juan@company.co.za",
        "from": "elk@company.co.za",
        "subject": "ELK - ERRORS caused by CreditDecisionServiceAPI.",
        "body": "{{payload.hits.total}} ERRORS caused by CreditDecisionServiceAPI. Threshold is 100."
      }
    },
    "Slack Action": {
      "throttle_period": "0h0m0s",
      "slack": {
        "channel": "#alerts",
        "message": "{{payload.hits.total}} ERRORS caused by CreditDecisionServiceAPI. Threshold is 100.",
        "stateless": false
      }
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
        "index": [
          "*"
        ],
        "types": [],
        "body": {
          "size": 0,
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "appName": "CreditDecisionServiceAPI"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match": {
                    "level": "ERROR"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "range": {
                    "timestamp": {
                      "from": "now-1d"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "script": {
      "script": "payload.hits.total > 100"
    }
  },
  "transform": {},
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "later": "every 15 minutes"
    }
  },
  "disable": true,
  "report": false,
  "title": "watcher_CreditDecisionServiceAPI_Errors"
}
```

So to be clear, this is the part that's being ignored by the query:

```
{
  "range": {
    "timestamp": {
      "from": "now-1d"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we've FINALLY solved the problem!

Elastic search has changes their DSL multiple times, so please note that you need to look at what version you're using for the correct solution. We're on Version: 6.2.3

Below query finally worked:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "appName": "CreditDecisionServiceAPI"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "level": "ERROR"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-1d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change it and add the **filter** Json tag before the **range** one, like that:

```
"filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-1d"

            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

Comment: They've removed range from _filter_ and added it to _query_. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though! Also, for future readers, the above answer is correct for older versions.

Comment: Oh, watch out for the field types. In our case, for some reason we send a text field called _timestamp_, but the range needed a datetime field called _@timestamp_.

Comment: actually in our system the field called  `@timestamp` as well but I tried to wrote this variable in a corresponding way for your system - and you are right,  I wrote you the answer for elastic **5.x**.